# asp.net mvc Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I am currently reading Manning's "ASP.NET MVC 4 in Action" book and trying to get the first example to work.

Within my test application, I built a simple Model and created some Views. I then imported "SQL Server Compact" using NuGet.

When I finally try to run the application I get the following error:

```
Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'
```

This occurs on every interaction with the Database (SELECT or other CRUD operations) I am running. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though, I am bit late to respond to this question but I was facing the same issue and I resolved it by modifying the connection string like below

```
 <add name="MovieDBContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Hope this would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 3):

I tried finding a solution for this particular error without success.

Fixed it in the end by updating the .Net Framework 4 to 4.0.2. Patch and details can be found [Here is the link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27756)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I think the problems here is string in web.config is not correct
According to your set up sql, the string will work if you set something similar like this

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
       connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
```

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; --> sometime, it will be Data Source=.;
after that, you need config right to access FOlder App_Data
If u test on Window 7, right click folder. property
Security tab -> add user network Service with full right

Comment: It worked for me by changing to `data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;` and adding the `NETWORK SERVICE` user with full control under the security tab of the App_Data folder's properties.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to  section of Web.config and modify the section to the following to get SQLServerCE4 to be used:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
<parameters>
<parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess problem occurs only when using SQL Express on .NET Framework v4.0.30319 anyways
SQL Server Express Local Database Runtime support in SqlClient is added in .NET Framework update 4.0.2  read - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544514

Alternately use connection string similar to this

```
<add name="EmployeeDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Employees;AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\Employees.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<add name="myconstr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydata.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

above connection string was giving an error but as soon as added"\" before the name of my database the error got resolved.

Try this:

```
<add name="myconstr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydata.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post I found about that error. It is a bit old, but uses the express version of sql server. [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/1d67d33b-0728-4951-8f11-4036be883d55/)

That blog post talks about expecting the server name of the sql database to be a local address and not /sqlexpress

There is also this [blog post](http://forums.asp.net/t/966680.aspx) that talks about having an incorrect connection string. So maybe check your connection string to the database. and your problem could be there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL Server Compact 4.0:

Be sure you have installed SQL Server Compact 4.0.

Install [VS 2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212219).

Change your connection string to:

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyModelDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|mymodel.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Right click on controllers folder and -> add -> controller

Type:

```
YourController
MVC-Controller with read/write ...
MyModel
new datacontext -> APP.Models.DatabaseContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, I have looked over my connection string and found that "UNC-style" paths e.g. `\\MyServer\MyDBServer` are *not* allowed, one has to use the `MyServer\MyDBServer` syntax for a remote host **or** the `.\MyDBServer` syntax for locally hosted DB Servers.