# The selected value from a DropDownList to be reflected in a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a web application that will use a `DropDownList` to have a user choose a certain value and a `DataList` to show certain data. For instance, if the user selects a value from the `DropDownList`, only data related to the user selected value should be shown in the `DataList`. I am very new to ASP.NET and to C#.

The code below is what I have implemented in my code behind file. Currently I am getting an `ArgumentException` error I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet dset;
    string connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|@Registration.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    string sql = "select * from Products";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connstring); //<--ArgumentException error occurs here
            dset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ProductID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DataListBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataListBind();
    }
    public void DataListBind()
    {
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Products where ProductID=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", connstring);
        dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset);
        dlProducts.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        dlProducts.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your connection string, if it is correct one.

Comment: @mybirthname I copied and pasted the connection string from the `Web.config` file. My connection string has a name and I tried that, and still get the same error. So instead I thought it would fix the issue by directly copying and pasting the connection string itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you connection string. If you look at the inner exception that you get it says:

> Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135081/asp-net-mvc-invalid-value-for-key-attachdbfilename) is further help on this matter.

To get rid of the exception just add a `@` in front of the string:

```
string connstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|@Registration.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have'nt created a connection object. I think you need to create and open the connection first.