# Error Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' when I using my program in other PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, localdb, mdf

I wrote a program with a database in VS2012, when I want to run this in another computer I get an Error

> Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

My Connection String is :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BMS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

I install SqlLocalDB_x86.MSI but still I get this Error
I use windows 10 and I wrote my program in Visual Studio 2012 with LinqtoSQL

I search very much in web but can not to solve this problem

Comment: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135081/asp-net-mvc-invalid-value-for-key-attachdbfilename)