# How to connect local TSQL to C# in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t-sql, visual-studio-2017

I am currently trying to create a program that is like a school management/timeInOut system.

I am using T-SQL as that is the default SQL version within visual studio as I thought this would be easier as they are fairly integrated. The problem I am having is the error:
 System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.'

With the connection string being:

```
string ConString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =| DataDirectory |\GardenRegister.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
```

are there any ideas what is wrong and why it wont recognise the database, If possible I would also like someone to be in personal contact to help aid me in this as there are a few problems I have encountered.

Comment: stupid question but is there GardenRegister.mdf in the app_data folder for the app?

Comment: XD, Yes there should be I did create it in the same location.
Is there any chance i can send you the program via  zip on google drive or something for you to have a look at?

Comment: maybe the spaces between pipes and DataDirectory? see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12135081/1132334)

Comment: Somehow that tiny edit worked, you my friend are a genius but now i receive another error further down:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'GardenRegister.Member'.'

This is the only problem with making a local database

EDIT:
FIXED THE DATABSE OPENS NOW

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED DUE TO THE COMMENTS

"maybe the spaces between pipes and DataDirectory? see also here – dlatikay" 
Thank you

```
string ConString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\GardenRegister.mdf; Integrated Security = True";

        string CombQuery = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.Member;";
```

This worked perfectly