# .NET5 WPF Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ado.net, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 WPF project, which connects to an another projects in the same solution. If I want to load any data from the DB, I get an error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.' ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

The connection string:

```
<add name="Booking_DatabaseEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Booking_Model.csdl|res://*/Booking_Model.ssdl|res://*/Booking_Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Booking_Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

In the same solution there is a command line projects, which uses the same connection string, but it is working correctly and can use this DB.

Do you have any idea to solve this error?

Comment: Your connection string seems a bit off. Can you try modifying it to a format mention in this link and try again? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752748/3526177

Comment: I tried that, but the same error: <add name="Booking_DatabaseEntities"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Booking_Database.mdf;
                       Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />